# How to bridge the gap between finite and infinite index sets in the proof of sigma subadditivity?

Tags: probability-theory

From a standard probability theory course, there is an exercise to prove that $$P\bigg(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\bigg) \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(A_k)$$

for some probability measure $P$, and countable (not necessarily disjoint) family of events $(A_k)$.

I assumed it should be relatively simple: When I first tried proving this I had something along the lines of $$P\bigg(\bigcup_{k=1}^N A_k\bigg) = \sum_{k=1}^N P(A_k) - \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} P\bigg(\bigcup_{k=1}^{N-j} A_k \bigcap A_{N-j+1}\bigg)$$

where the formula above is true for any $N$ (if I have written it correctly, but the crux of the question is less about the exact formula), which can be proved by induction.

Back then I assumed I could simply go from the above to concluding sigma subadditivity. But revisiting this I realise this is wrong; the claim I proved via induction is for every finite index set, but it is NOT for a single countably infinite set.

Is there any way to salvage this approach?

Comment: Countable additivity for disjoint events is part of the definition of a probability measure; you'll need to use that.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\mathbf{P}(A \cup B) = \mathbf{P}(A) + \mathbf{P}(B) - \mathbf{P}(A \cap B) \leq \mathbf{P}(A) + \mathbf{P}(B)$ since $\mathbf{P} \geq 0.$ By induction, we reach $\mathbf{P} \left( \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^N A_n \right) \leq \mathbf{P}(A_N) + \mathbf{P} \left( \bigcup\limits_{n = 1}^{N-1} A_n \right) \leq \sum\limits_{n = 1}^N \mathbf{P}(A_n).$ The events $\bigcup\limits_{n = 1}^N A_n$ *increase* to $\bigcup\limits_{k \in \mathbf{N}} A_k.$ Therefore, $\mathbf{P} \left(\bigcup\limits_{n = 1}^N A_n \right) \to \mathbf{P} \left(\bigcup\limits_{k \in \mathbf{N}} A_k \right);$ obviously $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N \mathbf{P}(A_n) \to \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty \mathbf{P}(A_k).$

Comment: The inclusion-exclusion formula is fine but it is not needed to reach your desired result, you only need to prove subadditivity for finite unions first and then using monotonicity of the probability measure conclude.

Comment: Thank for this, but I'm still not sure I follow where the limit of the unions comes from? I'm actually not even sure I know what we mean by the limit of a sequence of sets?

Comment: @masiewpao An _increasing_ sequence of sets if a family of sets satisfying $A_1 \subset A_2 \subset \ldots$ and the _limit_ of this family is defined by $\bigcup\limits_{n = 1}^\infty A_n.$ A _decreasing_ sequence is defined similarly, its limit is the _intersection_ of all the sets in the family. (These definitions can be generalised to the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of _any sequence_ of sets and the _limit of a sequence of sets_ is then defined to exists when the $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ coincide). Probability measures are continuous  over these type of limits (i.e. $P(\lim ...) = \lim P(...)$

Answer (score 0):

Whatb you have proved shows that $$P\bigg(\bigcup_{k=1}^N A_k\bigg) (= \sum_{k=1}^N P(A_k) - \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} P\bigg(\bigcup_{k=1}^{N-j} A_k \bigcap A_{N-j+1}\bigg)) \leq \sum_{k=1}^N P(A_k).$$ Now letting $N \to \infty$ finishes the proof since $\bigcup_{k=1}^N A_k$ increases to $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k$

Comment: I think what I am unclear on is exactly this last step, why does the LHS tending to infinity equal the RHS? That is, why is it that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \cup_{k=1}^n A_k = \cup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$?

Comment: @masiewpao For that you must use the axioms of measure. Using the axioms, you can show that if $A_n \nearrow A$, then $P(A_n) \nearrow P(A)$.